# Ambiguity in "Joe and David discussed his plans for tomorrow evening"

Tags: english, terminology, pronouns, ambiguity

Is there a specific term for the ambiguity in the sentence, "Joe and David discussed his plans for tomorrow evening," the ambiguity arising from the use of "his" when it could refer to either Joe or David? This question has been hard to Google.

Comment: anaphoric ambiguity? pronominal ambiguity?

Comment: With no further context, _his_ most likely refers to a third person to me, not to Joe or David.

Comment: How is this a duplicate? It is specifically asking the term for it.